# array sorting using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Is there a way to use descriptors in PHP to do the following sort:

**Array 1:**

> $array1 = ["blah", "quack", "yot"];

**Array 2**

`$array2 = [1,9,6];` Essentially, I'm trying to describe blah with 1, quack with 9, and yot with 6. Basically, there are a total of 1 blahs, 9 quacks, and 6 yots. When I sort the arrays, I want to produce the following arrays:

**Array 1 Sorted:**

```
$array1 = ["quack","yot","blah"];
```

**Array 2 Sorted:**

```
$array2 = [9,6,1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_multisort($array2, SORT_DESC, $array1);
```

http://ideone.com/4Afyu

http://php.net/array_multisort

Answer (score 0):

You can sort arrays with [`usort`](http://php.net/usort).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can restructure your data into an associative array.

$var = array ('blah'=>1, 'quack'=>9, 'yot'=>6);

So that your data is in one array. Then you can use asort or any php sorting function to manipulate the array.